# Objective C plist searching and random entry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, plist

another couple of questions about plists and objective c for the iphone.
Both questions relate to my plist which can be seen in my last [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627608/objective-c-using-the-correct-part-of-a-plist-and-looping-through-to-grab-data).

First thing is to do with searching, I know this is possible but what is the correct way to go about this? Should I pull all the searchable objects into an array and use this to build a table? Or is it possible to itereate through the plist and simply just show the matches? Or is there some other way I am missing here? As a quick example in the following I would want to bring back the two 'Jones' results:

```
<dict>
    <key>A</key>
    <array>
        <string>A Jones</string>
        <string>A King</string>
    </array>
    <key>T</key>
    <array>
        <string>T Jones</string>
        <string>T King</string>
    </array>
```

Secondly, is it possible to call up a random result from the plist, I'm pretty sure it is, but again what would be the correct way to go about this?

I will admit to finding the plist a bit of a pain as it seems to me like a bit of a rubbish form of xml. And I am still finding iterating through a plist dictionary pretty confusing to some degree. Still, any thoughts on these two questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obviously possible to iterate through a `NSDictionary` values using `-(NSEnumarator *)objectEnumerator;`, you can also retrieve all the values with `-(NSArray *)allValues;` and you could also have a look to `-(NSSet *)keysOfEntriesPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))predicate;` which returns a `NSSet` containing the keys for the value have passed the test (from Mac OS X 10.6).

About the second question, I think there's no 'better' way. Here is how I would do that :

1. Get all the keys of the `NSDictionary` using `-(NSArray *)allKeys;`
2. Get a random number
3. Pick up a key in the array using `-(id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex;`
4. Retrieve the corresponding object in the dictionary using : `-(id)objectForKey:(id)aKey;`

Then you got your object.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple way to iterate over the values in the `NSDictionary` :

```
// assuming you already have a well initialized dictionary
// first create a container
NSMutableArray *selectedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// then retrieve an enumerator for the dictionary
NSEnumerator *e = [theDictionary objectEnumerator];
id anObject;
// iterate...
while((anObject = [e nextObject]) != nil) {
    // do what you want with the object
    // in your case each object is an array
    NSArray *theArray = (NSArray *)anObject;
    // ...
    // if you find any of them interesting put it in the first array
    if([[theArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Jones"]) {
        [selectedObjects addObject:[theArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}
// here are the selected objects in selectedObjects.
// you won't forget to release selectedObjects when you don't need it anymore
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, shall have a play about and see what I can come up with... wish me luck!

Comment: good luck ! I don't worry for that since my answer is complete

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the OP's question how his app is actually using the random value, but if the app doesn't need the key in that situation, he could use `-allValues` to get an `NSArray` of its values and pick one at random instead of starting out by picking a random key.

Comment: That's right! Here was the way I often use to do that, but in this code, there's no need indeed to pick up a key before, you are right.

Comment: Right well I am getting somewhere with some tests, however iterating through my plist is proving to be a problem... If you could give me some advice on how to do this that would be incredibly handy. The plist can be seen in my original question linked above. (its been a long day today i tell you...)

Comment: And I got it all sorted! Cheers @Vince the help is hugely appreciated indeed!

Comment: great, don't forget there are some other ways to do that